# Calling fallback function in truffle to delegate a call

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, fallback-function, delegatecall

I'm playing with the upgradeable contracts *via* [DelegateProxy](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/proxy_delegate.html) in Solidity.

This pattern posits that a [MutableForwarder](https://github.com/fbielejec/truffle-forwarder/blob/master/contracts/proxy/MutableForwarder.sol) contract is deployed once, and all the subsequent calls to the [upgradeable contract](https://github.com/fbielejec/truffle-forwarder/blob/master/contracts/TestContract.sol) are made to the fallback function of the Forwarder, which in turn uses *delegatecall* to invoke the target contract.

I have a hard time calling the fallback function:

```
var payload = testContract.contract.construct.getData(1);

return web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: accounts[0],
  to: testContractForwarder.address,
  data: payload
});
```

The results of running the deployment script:

```
Replacing TestContract...
  TestContract: 0x93d8c7d954a930f2eadf6fc68058e5c43ebe988f
Deploying TestContractForwarder...
  TestContractForwarder: 0xd46539cae056345ce547e65c3e8d8ec764ed5d1d
@@@ TestContractForwarder target: 0x93d8c7d954a930f2eadf6fc68058e5c43ebe988f
```

After linking the target to the forwarder, next transaction goes through, but has no effect:

```
@@@ TestContract/construct tx 0x11bea1b01e4977747bfd8b604eaf9fc3ebc5dae2b42bde7e918f811fbad1fd53 successful
--- TestContract/value : 0
--- TestContract/wasConstructed : false
```

Calling the contract directly, with the same payload is successful and sets the value.

Repository which reproduces: https://github.com/fbielejec/truffle-forwarder

Comment: Can you make a Github repo with your contract code and the migration scripts?

Comment: sure, see the edited question.

Comment: In your migration script, the first thought I had was "why don't you `.then` all the actions?" From the look of it, there are a large number of independent promise chains, and it is unclear in which order they will complete. Can you `.then` all in a very strict fashion?

Comment: Second thought is "why do you `linkBytecode` with a fake `beefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeef`?".

Comment: a) I don't think this is neccessary, or even part of the problem, the steps are queued https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer and the logged output confirms that. b) to replace the target contract address in the bytecode.

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what a forwarder does when it uses `delegatecall`. What `delegatecall` does is use the code of elsewhere to run in the context of the contract that used `delegatecall`.

So if your instance of `TestContractForwarder` "delegate calls" the code of `TestContract`, then you can expect the storage of your instance of **`TestContractForwarder`** to be updated.

Let's review your migration script. You write:

```
var payload = testContract.contract.construct.getData(1);
return web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: address,
    to: testContractForwarder.address,
    data: payload,
    gas: gas
});
```

Which you can change to:

```
return TestContract.at(testContractForwarder.address)
    .construct(1, { from: address, gas: gas })
```

Then when you want to confirm the change, you need to change your:

```
    return TestContract.deployed ();
}).then ((instance) => {
    return [instance.value (), instance.wasConstructed ()];
}).then ((promises) => {
    return Promise.all (promises);
```

Into:

```
    return TestContractForwarder.deployed (); // <-- Notice the difference
}).then ((instance) => {
    var myContract = TestContract.at(instance.address);
    return Promise.all([myContract.value (), myContract.wasConstructed ()]);
```

So now you have a problem. You see, `MutableForwarder` stores `target` at storage slot `0`, and `TestContract` stores `value` at storage `0` too. So when you call `.construct`, in effect, you overwrite the `target` field.

To fix it, you need to have `TestContract` have a dummy field at storage slot `0`. Like so:

```
contract TestContract {

  uint private dummyTargetDontUpdate; // Storage slo 0
  uint public value; // slot 1
  bool public wasConstructed; // slot 2
```

---

I rewrote your migration script:

```
  deployer.deploy (TestContract, opts)
    .then (instance => {
      linkBytecode(TestContractForwarder, forwarderTargetPlaceholder, instance.address);
      return deployer.deploy(TestContractForwarder, opts);
    })
    .then (instance => instance.target())
    .then (res => {
      console.log ("@@@ TestContractForwarder target:",  res);
      return Promise.all([ TestContract.deployed(), TestContractForwarder.deployed() ]);
    })
    .then (([testContract, testContractForwarder]) => TestContract.at(testContractForwarder.address)
        .construct(1, { from: address, gas: gas }))
    .then (tx => {
      console.log ("@@@ TestContract/construct tx", tx.tx, "successful");
      return TestContractForwarder.deployed();
    })
    .then (instance => {
      var myContract = TestContract.at(instance.address);
      return Promise.all([ myContract.value(), myContract.wasConstructed() ]);
    })
    .then (([res1, res2]) => {
      console.log ("--- TestContract/value :", res1.c [0]);
      console.log ("--- TestContract/wasConstructed :", res2);
      console.log ("Done");
    });
```

Comment: That's a very well put together answer, thank you.